# I want to make 32bit INF driver file to 64bit INF

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, macbook

I am reviving MacBook Pro 2006 Late and installed Windows 7 64 bit on that. But the ATi Mobility Radeon X1600 driver only have 32 bit driver so Windows refuses installing driver. It says no required line in the inf file.
So I want to fix this and want to install driver.
The driver folder I downloaded is here https://download.cnet.com/ATI-Mobility-Radeon-X1600/3000-2108_4-170243.html
and in the inf file;

```
;-----------------------------------------------
; ATI Display Information file : atiilhag.inf
;
; Installation INF for the ATI display driver.
; Copyright(C) 1998-2006 ATI Technologies Inc.
;
; Windows Vista (Beta2 RI14)
;
; Base INF Last Updated Mar 7, 2006
;-----------------------------------------------

[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider=%ATI%
ClassGUID={4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Display
DriverVer=11/24/2006, 8.31.100.32
;;LayoutFile=layout.inf
CatalogFile=CL_39639.CAT

[SignatureAttributes]
atiumdva.dll=SignatureAttributes.PETrust
atiumdag.dll=SignatureAttributes.PETrust

[SignatureAttributes.PETrust]
PETrust=true

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir  = 11
R300.Miniport   = 12  ; drivers
R300.Display    = 11  ; system32

[ControlFlags]
ExcludeFromSelect=*
;
; Driver information
;

[Manufacturer]
%ATI% = ATI.Mfg

[ATI.Mfg]
"ATI Mobility Radeon X1600" = ati2mtag_M56, PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_71C5&SUBSYS_820B104D
;
; General installation section
;

[ati2mtag_M56]
Include=msdv.inf
FeatureScore=F6
CopyFiles=R300.Miniport, R300.Display
AddReg = ati2mtag_SoftwareDeviceSettings
AddReg = ati2mtag_M56_SoftwareDeviceSettings
AddReg = ati2mtag_Mobile_SoftwareDeviceSettings
DelReg = ati2mtag_RemoveDeviceSettings
DelFiles = R300.DelFiles
RegisterDlls = TMM.RegisterDlls

[r300.Miniport]
atikmdag.sys
ativcaxx.cpa
ativcaxx.vp
ativvpxx.vp
ativpkxx.vp
ativokxx.vp
ativdkxx.vp
ati2erec.dll

[r300.Display]
atiumdag.dll,,,0x00004000             ; COPYFLG_IN_USE_TRY_RENAME
atiumdva.dll,,,0x00004000             ; COPYFLG_IN_USE_TRY_RENAME
atitmmxx.dll,,,0x00004000
atiicdxx.dat,,,0x00004000
atiumdva.dat
;;atiogl32.dll
Ati2evxx.exe,,,0x00004000
Ati2evxx.dll,,,0x00004000
atipdlxx.dll,,,0x00004000
ati2edxx.dll,,,0x00004000

[r300.DelFiles]
ativvaxx.dll
;
;Register COM object
;

[TMM.RegisterDlls]
11,,atitmmxx.dll,1
;
; Service Installation
;

[ati2mtag_M56.Services]
AddService = R300, 0x00000002, R300_Service_Inst, R300_EventLog_Inst
AddService = Ati External Event Utility, 0x00000000, Ati2evxx_Generic_Service_Inst, Ati2evxx_EventLog_Inst

[R300_Service_Inst]
ServiceType    = 1                  ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType      = 3                  ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl   = 0                  ; SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE
LoadOrderGroup = Video
ServiceBinary  = %12%\atikmdag.sys

[R300_EventLog_Inst]
AddReg = R300_EventLog_AddReg

[R300_EventLog_AddReg]
HKR,,EventMessageFile,0x00020000,"%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\ati2erec.dll"
HKR,,TypesSupported,0x00010001,7
HKR,, CategoryMessageFile, 0x00020000, "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\ati2erec.dll"
HKR,, CategoryCount, 0x00010001, 63

[Ati2evxx_Generic_Service_Inst]
ServiceType    = 0x110
StartType      = 2
ErrorControl   = 1
ServiceBinary  = %11%\Ati2evxx.exe
LoadOrderGroup = Event log

[Ati2evxx_EventLog_Inst]
AddReg=Ati2evxx_EventLog_AddReg

[Ati2evxx_EventLog_AddReg]
HKR,,EventMessageFile,0x00020000,"%11%\Ati2evxx.exe"
HKR,,TypesSupported,0x00010001,7

[ati2mtag_M56.HW]
AddReg = atikmdag_MSI_HardwareDeviceSettings

[ati2mtag_M56_SoftwareDeviceSettings]
HKR,, DALRULE_NOTVANDLCDONCRTC,             %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, WmAgpMaxIdleClk,              %REG_DWORD%,    0x20
HKR,, DisableIDCT,                          %REG_DWORD%,    0
;;HKLM,"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",ATIModeChange,,"Ati2mdxx.exe"
HKR,, DALR6 CRT_MaxModeInfo,                  %REG_BINARY%,00,00,00,00,40,06,00,00,B0,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,3C,00,00,00
HKR,, DisableFullAdapterInit,      %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, MemInitLatencyTimer,         %REG_DWORD%,    0x775771BF
HKR,, GCORULE_FlickerWA,             %REG_DWORD%, 1
HKR,, SMOOTHVISION_NAME, %REG_SZ%, "SMOOTHVISION HD"
HKR, "UMD",GI_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 1
HKR,, AreaAniso_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR,, SameOnAllUsingStandardInVideoTheaterCloneMode, %REG_SZ%, "1"
HKR,, GI_NA, %REG_SZ%, 1
HKR,, VIDEO_NAME_SUFFIX, %REG_SZ%, "Avivo(TM)"
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD1, %REG_BINARY%,12,80,07,68,00,00,00,60,12,80,07,68,00,00,00,75,12,80,07,68,00,00,00,85,13,60,07,68,00,00,00,00,16,80,10,50,00,00,00,60,19,20,10,80,00,00,00,85,10,24,06,00,00,00,00,60,14,00,10,50,00,00,00,60
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD1, %REG_BINARY%,07,20,04,80,00,00,00,00,07,20,05,76,00,00,00,00,08,48,04,80,00,00,00,00,10,24,06,00,00,00,00,00,11,52,08,64,00,00,00,00,14,00,10,50,00,00,00,00,17,92,13,44,00,00,00,00,18,00,14,40,00,00,00,00
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD2, %REG_BINARY%,18,56,13,92,00,00,00,00,19,20,14,40,00,08,00,00,19,20,14,40,00,16,00,00,19,20,14,40,00,24,00,00,19,20,14,40,00,32,00,00,20,48,15,36,00,00,00,00
HKR,, DALRULE_ALLOWINFPANELVENDORID,    %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, DALRULE_OVERWRITEPANELVENDORID, %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, DisableDualView,                 %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, DisableDualviewWithHotKey,    %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, TVDisableModes,   %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, DisableSWInterrupt,              %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, ExtEvent_BIOSEventByInterrupt,      %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, TVM6Flag,   %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, DfpUsePixSlip,                  %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, GCOOPTION_DefaultOvlBrightness, %REG_DWORD%, 0xffffffed
HKR,, GCOOPTION_DefaultOvlSaturation, %REG_DWORD%, 0x86
HKR,, GCOOPTION_DefaultOvlContrast, %REG_DWORD%, 0x6a
HKR, "UMD",Main3D_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 3
HKR, "UMD",AntiAlias_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 1
HKR, "UMD",AntiAliasSamples_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",AnisoType_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",AnisoDegree_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",TextureOpt_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",TextureLod_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",TruformMode_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",VSyncControl_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 1
HKR, "UMD",SwapEffect_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",TemporalAAMultiplier_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",ExportCompressedTex_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 1
HKR, "UMD",PixelCenter_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",ForceZBufferDepth_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR, "UMD",EnableTripleBuffering_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 0
HKR,, ColourDesktopGamma_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "1.0 1.0 1.0"
HKR,, ColourDesktopBrightness_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "0 0 0"
HKR,, ColourDesktopContrast_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "1.0 1.0 1.0"
HKR,, ColourFullscreenGamma_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "1.0 1.0 1.0"
HKR,, ColourFullscreenBrightness_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "0 0 0"
HKR,, ColourFullscreenContrast_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "1.0 1.0 1.0"
HKR,, 3D_Refresh_Rate_Override_DEF, %REG_DWORD%, 0
HKR,, Display_Detection_DEF, %REG_DWORD%, 0
HKR,, Panning_Mode_DEF, %REG_DWORD%, 0
HKR,, Force_TV_Detection_DEF, %REG_DWORD%, 0
HKR,, CatalystAI_DEF, %REG_SZ%, 1

[ati2mtag_SoftwareDeviceSettings]
HKR,, DDC2Disabled,                         %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, DisableBlockWrite,                    %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, DisableDMACopy,                       %REG_DWORD%,    0
;;HKR,, InstalledDisplayDrivers,              %REG_MULTI_SZ%, framebuf
HKR,, InstalledDisplayDrivers,              %REG_MULTI_SZ%, atiumdag, atiumdva, atitmmxx
HKR,, UserModeDriverName,                   %REG_MULTI_SZ%, atiumdag.dll
HKR,, KMDTst,                               %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, MultiFunctionSupported,               %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, TestEnv,                              %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, TimingSelection,                      %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, VgaCompatible,                        %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,,"Adaptive De-interlacing",             %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,,"VPE Adaptive De-interlacing",         %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, GCOOPTION_DisableGPIOPowerSaveMode,   %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKLM,"Software\ATI Technologies\CBT",ReleaseVersion,,"8.31.100.3.2-061124a2-039639C-Sony"
HKR,, ReleaseVersion,,"8.31.100.3.2-061124a2-039639C-Sony"
HKR,, BuildNumber,,"09700"
HKR,, UserModeDriverGUID,     %REG_SZ%, {"4242B984-6C36-4FC8-8626-DE5E8B11886D"}
HKR,, DALGameGammaScale,       %REG_DWORD%,   0x00646464
HKLM, "Software\CLASSES\CLSID\{EBB5845F-CA80-11CF-BD3C-008029E89281}\InProcServer32",ThreadingModel,,"Both"
HKLM,"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Media Foundation",EMUOPM, %REG_DWORD%, 0
HKR,, GXOPPUseExclusiveExecution,  %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR, "UMD\DXVA",DI_METHOD, %REG_SZ%, "-1"
HKR, "UMD\DXVA",DI_METHOD_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "-1"
HKR, "UMD\DXVA",DI_METHOD_NA, %REG_SZ%, "0"
HKR, "UMD\DXVA",3to2Pulldown, %REG_SZ%, "1"
HKR, "UMD\DXVA",3to2Pulldown_NA, %REG_SZ%, "0"
HKR, "UMD\DXVA",3to2Pulldown_DEF, %REG_SZ%, "1"
HKLM,"Software\Microsoft\TMM",UseIViewHelper, %REG_DWORD%, 1
HKR,, DXVA_WMV_NA, %REG_SZ%, "1"
HKR,, DisableTiling,                        %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, DisableMMSnifferCode,               %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, TVForceDetection,   %REG_DWORD%,    0
HKR,, DALDisplayPrioritySequence, %REG_BINARY%, 08,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,20,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,40,00,00,00,80,00,00,00
HKR,, TVEnableOverscan,      %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, AutoColorDepthReduction_NA,   %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKLM,"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Atierecord",eRecordEnable,          %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKLM,"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Atierecord",eRecordEnablePopups,          %REG_DWORD%,    1

[atikmdag_MSI_HardwareDeviceSettings]
HKR,Interrupt Management\MessageSignaledInterruptProperties, MSISupported, 0x00010001, 1

[ati2mtag_Mobile_SoftwareDeviceSettings]
HKR,, RemovableSources,                      %REG_DWORD%,    2
HKR,, DALRULE_ENABLESHOWACSLIDER,                  %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, DALRULE_ENABLESHOWDCLOWSLIDER,                  %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, ExtEvent_EnableAutoDisplayConfig,      %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, ExtEvent_SaveADCProfileGlobally,      %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, ExtEvent_NonExtendedADCProfileOnHotKey,      %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, DALRULE_ADDEXTDESKTOPTOPROFILEKEY,      %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, DALRULE_PROFILEPREFERREDMODEBASEDONEXTDEVICE,                  %REG_DWORD%,    1
HKR,, DALOPTION_MinResBCD,  %REG_BINARY%, 00,00,00,00,00,00,00,60

[ati2mtag_RemoveDeviceSettings]
HKR,, Adaptive De-interlacing
HKR,, AgpLevel
HKR,, AntiAlias
HKR,, DALCurrentObjectData
HKR,, DALLastConnected
HKR,, DALLastSelected
HKR,, DALLastTypes
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD
HKR,, DALObjectData
HKR,, DALObjectData0
HKR,, DALObjectData1
HKR,, DALR6 CRT_MaxModeInfo
HKR,, DALR6 CRT2_MaxModeInfo
HKR,, DALR6 DFP_MaxModeInfo
HKR,, DALR6 DFPx_MaxModeInfo
HKR,, DALR6 GCO_Index0
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD
HKR,, DALRULE_ADDNATIVEMODESTOMODETABLE
HKR,, DALRULE_CRTSUPPORTSALLMODES
HKR,, DALRULE_DISABLEBANDWIDTH
HKR,, DALRULE_DISPLAYSRESTRICTMODES
HKR,, DALRULE_NOCRTANDLCDONSAMECONTROLLER
HKR,, DALRULE_NOFORCEBOOT
HKR,, DALRULE_NOTVANDCRTONSAMECONTROLLER
HKR,, DALRULE_RESTRICTUNKNOWNMONITOR
HKR,, DALRULE_SAVEPANLOCK
HKR,, DALSelectObjectData0
HKR,, DALSelectObjectData1
HKR,, DDC2Disabled
HKR,, DefaultMode
HKR,, DFPRULE_HotplugSupported
HKR,, DisableAGP
HKR,, DisableAGPPM4
HKR,, DisableBlockWrite
HKR,, DisableDMA
HKR,, DisableDMACopy
HKR,, DisableDrvStretchBlt
HKR,, DisableDynamicEnableMode
HKR,, DisableEnumAllChilds
HKR,, DisableFullAdapterInit
HKR,, DisableHierarchicalZ
HKR,, DisableIDCT
HKR,, DisableLCD
HKR,, DisableMMLIB
HKR,, DisableOpenGLScrAccelerate
HKR,, DisablePllInit
HKR,, DisablePrimaryTiling
HKR,, DisableTCL
HKR,, DisableTimeStampWriteBack
HKR,, DisableUSWC
HKR,, DisableVPE
HKR,, EnableWaitUntilIdxTriList2
HKR,, GCORULE_HIGHDISPRI
HKR,, GCORULE_R200TVPLLWA
HKR,, KD_TilingMode
HKR,, LVB
HKR,, MaxAgpVb
HKR,, MaxAGPVB
HKR,, MaxLocalVb
HKR,, MaxLocalVB
HKR,, SubmitOnDraw
HKR,, TestEnv
HKR,, TimingSelection
HKR,, TVR200Flag
HKR,, VgaCompatible
HKR,, VPE Adaptive De-interlacing
HKR,, ATIPoll
HKR,, TVM6Flag
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD1
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD2
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD3
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD4
HKR,, DALNonStandardModesBCD5
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD1
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD2
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD3
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD4
HKR,, DALRestrictedModesBCD5
HKR,, RemovableSources
HKR,, TheaterMode_NA
HKR,, TVContrastDefaultNTSC
HKR,, HDTVRULE_HDTVGDOENABLE
HKR,, HDTVRULE_HDTVSIGNALFORMAT
HKR,, TVLumaFlicker
HKR,, TVDotCrawl
HKR,, TVCompositeFilter
HKR,, DisableCursor
HKR,, DALRULE_USERESTRICTEDNATIVETIMING
HKR,, DFPOption_MaxFreq
HKR,, DisableAGPFW
HKR,, CRTRULE_FORCECRTDAC1DETECTED
HKR,, CRTRULE_FORCECRTDAC2DETECTED
HKR,, CRTRULE_FORCECRTDACTYPESDETECTED
HKR,, GCORULE_TMDSReducedBlankingUseCVT
HKR,, DFPOption_SingleLink
HKR,, DFPXOption_SingleLink
HKR,, TVContrastDefaultNTSCJ
HKR,, TVContrastDefaultPAL
HKR,, R6LCD_ALLOWDISABLELOWREFRESHBYUSER
HKR,, TVDACSettings
HKR,, DAL_CRTRestrictedModesBCD
HKR,, GCORULE_ExtTMDSReduceBlankTiming
HKR,, GCOOPTION_ExtTMDSMaxTMDSClockSpeed
HKR,, OverDrive3_NA
HKR,, OverDrive2_NA
HKR,, DAL_CvRestrictedModesBCD
HKR,, AutoClockConfig_NA
HKR,, DALRULE_DISABLEVARIBRIGHTBYDEFAULT
HKR,, DALRULE_HIDEVARIBRIGHT
HKR,, GCORULE_CvImproveClkPrecision
HKR,, DALDefaultCvModeBCD
HKR,, DALRULE_CVUSEOPTIMODEASDEFAULT
HKR,, Gxo50HzTimingSupport
HKR,, DALRULE_LIMITEDGREYSCALESUPPORT
HKR,, Extevent_HotplugUseCurrentMapping
HKR,, ExtEvent_EnableADCTriggeredByTMM
HKR,, DAL_TVRestrictedModesBCD

[ati2mtag_M56.GeneralConfigData]
MaximumDeviceMemoryConfiguration=128
MaximumNumberOfDevices=4

[SourceDisksNames.x86]
1 = %DiskId%,,,.\B_39428

[SourceDisksFiles]
ati2edxx.dll=1
ati2erec.dll=1
ati2evxx.dll=1
ati2evxx.exe=1
atiicdxx.dat=1
atikmdag.sys=1
atipdlxx.dll=1
atitmmxx.dll=1
atiumdag.dll=1
atiumdva.dat=1
atiumdva.dll=1
ativcaxx.cpa=1
ativcaxx.vp=1
ativdkxx.vp=1
ativokxx.vp=1
ativpkxx.vp=1
ativvpxx.vp=1

[Strings]
;
; Non-Localizable Strings
;
REG_SZ         = 0x00000000
REG_MULTI_SZ   = 0x00010000
REG_EXPAND_SZ  = 0x00020000
REG_BINARY     = 0x00000001
REG_DWORD      = 0x00010001
SERVICEROOT    = "System\CurrentControlSet\Services"
;
; Localizable Strings
;
DiskId       = "ATI Technologies Inc. Installation DISK (VIDEO)"
GraphAdap    = "Graphics Adapter"
ATI          = "ATI Technologies Inc."
DisplayUninstall = "ATI Display Component Uninstall"
ATIR300="WDDM (R300)"
```

What line show I add? Please help me!

Comment: Microsoft have a whole raft of potential drivers at https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=ati+mobility+radeon+x1600 have you tried simply updating the driver through Windows Update? The first driver there is for AMD64 https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=68466401-ef3c-414c-96d3-79bfa7d06733

Comment: There isn’t a solution to your problem since the .INF file explicitly calls the driver binary file which of course is 32-bit

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks a lot!       ⍤⃝       ⍢⃝    ⍩⃝

Answer (score 2):

Even if you change the INF file, the driver binaries will still be 32-bit. However, it’s the driver binaries (at least the kernel space driver, `atikmdag.sys`) that need to be 64-bit.

You cannot change the binaries to be 64-bit. Only the software developer (AMD/ATI) can do that.

If there truly is no 64-bit Windows driver available for this GPU, you will not be able to use 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

Take a look at [Download Boot Camp Support Software](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?locale=en_US) and check, if the desired version is included.